# How to add estimators (Chao1, Chao2, ACE and ICE ) to the Species Accumulation Graph

Tags: r, plot, statistics, vegan

I have the following script that shows the plot of the accumulation curves for a forest environments, I would love to integrate the Chao1, Chao2, ACE and ICE indicators Graph (the matrix resulting of using 'fossil' packe function spp.est(x)) in the same accumulation curve, what I need to do to include them.

```
    x = structure(list(
        Achromoporus.occultus = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
        Achromoporus.platyurus = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
        Achromoporus.andujari = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
        Achromoporus.occultus.1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L),
        Achromoporus.platyurus.1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
        Achromoporus.vallenuevo = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L),
        Acromoporus.Andujari = c(4L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 0L),
        Acromoporus.concolor = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L),
        Acromoporus.occultus = c(2L, 3L, 10L, 16L, 1L),
        Acromoporus.Platyurus = c(1L, 6L, 3L, 15L, 3L),
        Acromoporus.Vallenuevo = c(4L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L),
        Docodesmus.angustus = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L),
        Docodesmus.Sp. = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L),
        Henicomus.Septiporus = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L),
        Morfo.A = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L),
        Morfo.B = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L),
        Prostemmiulus.gracilipes = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L),
        Prostemmiulus.Scaurus = c(0L, 0L, 4L, 3L, 5L),
        Prostemmiulus.setosus = c(1L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 6L),
        Siphonophora.platops = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L),
        Spirobolus.sp = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L),
        Spirobolus.sp.Morfo.A = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L),
        Syphonophora.Platops = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L)), 
        .Names = c(
            "Achromoporus.occultus",
            "Achromoporus.platyurus", 
            "Achromoporus.andujari",
            "Achromoporus.occultus.1",
            "Achromoporus.platyurus.1", 
             "Achromoporus.vallenuevo",
            "Acromoporus.Andujari",
            "Acromoporus.concolor", 
            "Acromoporus.occultus",
            "Acromoporus.Platyurus",
            "Acromoporus.Vallenuevo", 
            "Docodesmus.angustus",
            "Docodesmus.Sp.",
            "Henicomus.Septiporus", 
            "Morfo.A",
            "Morfo.B",
            "Prostemmiulus.gracilipes",
            "Prostemmiulus.Scaurus", 
            "Prostemmiulus.setosus",
            "Siphonophora.platops",
            "Spirobolus.sp", 
            "Spirobolus.sp.Morfo.A",
            "Syphonophora.Platops"), 
             row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")


    x = read.csv("Desktop/pine.csv")
    plot(specaccum(x), marker='.')
    legend('bottomright', c('Pine Forest'),
           col=1:3, lty=1, bty='n', inset=0.025)
```

Something like this picture.[image]

Comment: It is very unclear what you are asking for. Because you didn't include any sample data we can't run the code or see the output. What is produced by this code? How is what you want different than what is produced? Is there an example of the type of plot you are trying to create somewhere?

Comment: Presumably you want to use the `vegan` package and plot curves based on the procedures described here: http://www.uvm.edu/~ngotelli/manuscriptpdfs/Chapter%204.pdf (I do not use these approaches for species richness estimation myself.)

Comment: The approaches described in the above paper might also be available here. http://viceroy.eeb.uconn.edu/estimates/EstimateSPages/AboutEstimateS.htm  Although, again, I am not endorsing their use by providing the name of software that might estimate them.

Comment: @MrFlick which way is the best to give you and idea of my sample data?

Comment: See [how to make a great R reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for suggestions.

Comment: @MrFlick I added somedata to the answer, I hope is clear enough

Comment: This extra is very useful. Hopefully the question will soon be reopened. But I'm not sure what the final axes should be. The `spp.est` stuff seems to produce a value for each sample (column) in the data, but the `specaccum()` function seems to return a richness value for each site (row) of data. Is that the right data?

Comment: Yes, it is the right data, but only a subset of it.